# wordpress site support both English and Bangla

Tags: wordpress, multilingual

I make an website on wordpress. It must be supported by two  languages - English and Bangla. Users choose language option to select language. How can I set laguage support? Please reply as early as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use plugins, try using qtranslate https://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/

Comment: It is compatible up to: 3.8.3 not to recent version.

Comment: Well wordpress is created in a way that it supports all previous versions as well. There are a few functions that are deprecated but it should still work. Did you try using it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use WPML for multi language support.